# Prawn: how to set document's printable dimensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

I'm generating a pdf with prawn. Basically, I generate the document and I fill it with some images.
The problem comes when I download the file and I try to print it. The dimensions are not set to the ones I previously specified.

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(page_size: "A3", margin: PAGE_MARGIN, page_layout: :landscape)
```

When I try to print it, the default page size is "A4" instead of "A3"
How can I solve this?
I tried to attach some metadata but it didn't work correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using prawn 1.3.0:

```
require "prawn"

pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => 'A3')

pdf.text "Hello World!"

pdf.render_file("export.pdf")
```

in terminal:

> pdfinfo export.pdf

outputs:

```
Creator:        Prawn
Producer:       Prawn
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      841.89 x 1190.55 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      842 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

Comment: you are right, the dimensions are set correctly. The problem is that when a software is reading the pdf it doesn't set the size to the proper one, instead it use the default. Anyways it seems that prawn does its work and the problem is on the external software.

Comment: @dioshari What software are you using?

Comment: Even if I try to print with Preview of mac, I get a wrong default paper size.

Answer (score 3):

In the case where you're generating the document within its own class, this also works to declare the paper size:

```
class EnvelopePdf < Prawn::Document
    def initialize(_item_array, _type_of_item)
       super(:page_size => [324, 684], :page_layout => :landscape)   # 4.5" by 9.5", which is No 10 envelopes
   ... application-specific initialization code here ...
    print_the_envelopes
end
```